# ProGuard keep class does not work

Tags: java, proguard, obfuscation

I have a jar file and I would like to obfuscate it with ProGuard. All libraries into jar file and I would like to exclude libraries from obfuscation. When I try to obfuscate I get the following error:

```
Unexpected error while performing partial evaluation:
  Class       = [com/google/common/cache/LongAddables]
  Method      = [<clinit>()V]
  Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Can't find common super class of [com/google/common/cache/LongAddables$2] (with 1 known super classes) and [com/google/common/cache/LongAddables$1] (with 1 known super classes))
Error: Can't find common super class of [com/google/common/cache/LongAddables$2] (with 1 known super classes) and [com/google/common/cache/LongAddables$1] (with 1 known super classes)
```

My config is like this;

```
-injars       E:\project\celrond\out\artifacts\celrond-build.jar  
-outjars      E:\project\celrond\out\artifacts\celrond-build_obf.jar

-keep class com.google.** { *; }  
-keep class org.h2.** { *; }  
-keep class org.apache.** { *; }  
-keep class com.sun.** { *; }  
-keep class com.j256.** { *; }  
-keep class org.eclipse.** { *; }  
-keep class com.ibm.** { *; }  
-keep public class celrond.MyMain {  
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
```

I couldn't find out my mistake, any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that the guava library is missing as a libraryjar. Have you packaged all dependent libraries into the file `celron-build.jar`? If not, then you need to specify them as

```
-libraryjars path/to/library.jar
```

Comment: I have packaged all dependent libraries into the my jar file. I can run my program with 'java -jar celron-build.jar' command without any problem.

Comment: Can you verify that the class com.google.common.base.Supplier is present? Also can you post any warnings ProGuard outputs which might indicate the source of the problem.